# Sets proof question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that for the sets $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$

$$(A\times B)\cup(C\times D)\subseteq(A\cup C)\times (B\cup D)$$

General method I start of with for Cartesian products is letting $(a,b)\in A\times B$ and $(c,d)\in C\times D$.

Now I dont know how to manipulate the union of these two Cartesian products.

Comment: Hint in order to prove that $P\cup Q\subseteq R$ it is enough to prove that $P\subseteq R$ and $Q\subseteq R$.

Comment: Do you have the relevant definitions at hand? That is for cartesian product, union and subset? Then you should only need to apply those definitions. If something is a member of the LHS then it's either $(a,b)$ or $(c,d)$ and you need to show that then it's either way a member of $(A\cup C)\times(B\cup D)$

Answer (score 1):

Case 1.  Show if (x,y) in A×B, then (x,y) in $(A\cup C)\times (B\cup D).$

Case 2.  Show if (x,y) in C×D, then (x,y) in $(A\cup C)\times (B\cup D).$

Comment: I get confused about the two cases thing, in some books they give ttwo cases in the answers but in other books they only have one case? How many cases should i consider if a question like this comes on my test, ii know its technically correct to consider both cases but do i need to

Comment: You do not understand 'or'?